# If window is less than 768px wide, don't fire function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover, window-resize

If the window width on page load AND resize is less than 768px, I don't want to fire the `showCover()` function. With the below code, even when the window is less than 768px, it's still being fired.

```
    function ipsThemeViewer() {

        jQuery(window).resize(function() {
           if ( jQuery(window).width() < 768 ) return false;
           showCover();
        }).resize();

    }

    function showCover() {
        jQuery('#ipsThemeViewerScreen').hover(function () {
            var t = jQuery(this);
            jQuery('.cover').stop().fadeIn('fast');
        }, function () {
            var t = jQuery(this);
            jQuery('.cover').stop().fadeOut('fast');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you understand that `.hover()` binds event handlers, so they're being bound over and over again? This is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go the other way around:

```
jQuery(function($) {  // DOM READY AND SECURE $ ALIAS

    var winIsSmall;

    function testWinSize(){
        winIsSmall= $(window).width() < 768; // BOOLEAN
    }

    $(window).on("load resize", testWinSize);

    $('#ipsThemeViewerScreen').hover(function () {            
        if(winIsSmall){
            // need something here?
        }else{
            $('.cover').stop().fadeToggle('fast');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding something fundamental; but: `$(window).on('load resize', winIsSmall);`? Doesn't that just return `true`/`false` on `load` and `resize`? Does a Boolean there do something useful?

Comment: @DavidThomas Woooops. Edited, I was in hurry to make my late-night coffee.